# Why no images on a fresh Wordpress installation?

Tags: images

I've just installed Wordpress here at arun.sanspace.in But, don't know why, it doesn't display any images. I want to know why? I have another Wordpress installation on the same server which works great. What exactly is the problem here? Am I doing something wrong?

While I copy the image location from the placeholder and open it alone, it displays the picture. It happens on IE and FF both.

Comment: Had the same problem as you, your solution did not work.
This one did, though. http://www.wordpress-plugin.net/no-images-after-a-fresh-wordpress-installation/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured it out. I had enabled hotlink protection. I installed the new blog in a new subdomain which was not added to the hotlink protection. So, it prevented the image requests. Now I added to the list and everything's fine. Silly me. :-(